# How to find LTV of users with cohort analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics, data-analysis

How to calculate a user's LTV usage using cohort analysis (group event - trial registration, cohort represents the number of transactions)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps2Tt.jpg)

Comment: in column ['purchase_date'] datas about trial and not trial periods...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.